# When we use Yii RbAC?

Tags: yii, rbac

Because all the actions are done via Controllers in Yii, by means of controller filters and some checking in actions, a good security measure can be achieved. For sure this kind of checking is faster than RbAC (if my statements are wrong please let me know).

> So when exactly we find out that it's better to use Yii RbAC?

Answer (score 0):

Its a matter of personal preferences and tendency but probably when your authorization requirements are more complex. IMHO, it's easier and more intuitive to maintain complex permissions scheme using RBAC and some GUI extension to manage it (for example, I use RBAM & SRBAC extensions).